# Recover from accidentally deleting the azure tables

Tags: azure, azure-storage

http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=5292591

This kind of f*** up can easily be done in Azure tables - whenever I use Cerebrata, I have an unnerving feeling that I might screw up things with one click!

What are the best-practices of taking backups in azure storage (both table storage and the blob-storage) so that it can be repatched if something unfortunate happens.

Kapil

Answer (score 1):

As @Sandrino stated, lock down access to production data. Don't give out the storage account keys to anyone except the one or two people managing production rollouts. And if you *must* provide table access (say, for some type of emergency debugging), you can generate a Shared Access Signature for a table with just Query permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid accessing production databases, storage accounts, ... outside of your application. And set up backups, also for Table Storage.

You can use a commercial service like [RedGate Cloud Services](http://cloudservices.red-gate.com/).